# What will be the output of this and how?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The output of this code is

```
0 1 2 3
```

But I am not getting the **factorial part**. I mean `1!=1` (i.e. `i factorial equals to 1`), so it *does not* satisfy the condition, so type for input `2` and `3`, but they get *printed* as output?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     int i = 0;
     int b = 8, a = 32;
     for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
     {
         if ((a / b * 2)== 2)
         {
             Console.WriteLine( i + " ");
             continue;
         }
         else if (i!=4)
             Console.Write(i + " ");
         else
             break;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: What happened when you debugged through it?

Comment: `The output of this code should be 0 1 2 3.` That **is** what it outputs. _Also, the  `continue` is unnecessary._

Comment: I am not getting why it is printing that. i mean 1!=1, not 4,so it does not satisfy the condition,but printing 1 . why?

Comment: Wait, Do you want to get Factorial number??? What is your goal???

Comment: `else if (i != 4)` Can you explain to use what you **think** that line of code does?

Comment: oh, it is not factorial, != means not equal ... now i get it... sorry guyz,actually new to this programming world :P

Comment: Side note: in fact factorial (unless you switch from *integer* `i` to `floating point* and from factorial to *gamma function*) can't be equal to `4`, but `1`, `2`, `6`, `24`...

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's see:

```
   int b = 8, a = 32;

   ... 

   a / b * 2 == 32 / 8 * 2 == 4 * 2 == 8
```

That's why `if ((a / b * 2) == 2)` will *never* succeed, and so we can drop this `if` and simplify the loop into

```
   for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
     if (i != 4)                 // i != means "i doesn't equal", not "i factorial equals"
         Console.Write(i + " "); // print 0, 1, 2, 3
     else
         break;                  // break on 4
```

Here we can clearly see that the routine will be printing out `i` up to `4` So you have

```
   0 1 2 3
```

**Side note**: in order to avoid such errors, *format out* your code and let the  compiler help you:

```
   i!=4     // Bad, it can be read in different ways (not equal or factorial)
   i != 4   // i is not equal to 4
   i! = 4   // assign 4 to i factorial: compile time error
   i! == 4  // i factorial equals to 4: compile time error - C# doesn't have factorials
```

Comment: oh, it is not factorial, != means not equal ... now i get it... sorry,actually new to this programming world :P

Comment: In fact `!` means **not**, e.g. `a & !b` - `a` *and not* `b`; `==` - *equal*, `!=` *not equal*